# rails 5 not loading classes from custom folders app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created a new folder named `serializers` under `app` folder and added a new class named `SearchSerializer`.

When I am running the `Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths` command in rails console, Here is the output , But I am not sure , why `SearchSerializer` is not initialized ?

[image]

Comment: Did you restart spring after adding the new folder?

Answer (score 0):

Find the file `application.rb`

add the line

`config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/serializers"`

or add `"#{Rails.root}/app/serializers"` in the end of `config.autoload_paths += ...`

Comment: I already check, we do not need to add it manually. its already there in the auto load paths.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you either correctly named the file or the class. Please reveal your `SearchSerializer` class (contents, filename).